# Tiny URL using PHP for auto-twitts

Tags: php, twitter, tinyurl

I'm trying to implement auto post on Twitter using PHP.

But because of twitt's character limit I wanted to know how can I use tinyURL, instead of placing the full link, like http://www.appdropp.com/ios/stone-age-the-board-game/564247778

You see it's quite long...

I know services like:

- tinyurl.com
- goo.gl

But how can I use these services in bulk, to generate hundreds of links every day with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check Google API, but I'm not sure about that much bulk. 
I can suggest 3 solutions for you:

1. Create short links on your host using PHP.
2. Twitter will
   shorten the URL for you if you tweet **DIRECTLY**. But, you cannot do it
   using auto-posting. So, count characters (like `message + URL <= 140`)
   and keep your automatic tweets length less than 140 characters.
3. You can also try [this](http://thehungrycoder.com/scripts/url-shortening-using-php.html) (*Check the
   PHP Source Code Example*)

   ```
   function CompressURL($url) {
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://"."to.ly/api.php?longurl=".urlencode($url));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

      $shorturl = curl_exec ($ch);
      curl_close ($ch);

      return $shorturl;
   }
   echo CompressURL("http://twitter.com"); // Test
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
**This method depends upon TinyURL page structure which may be changed in near future and don't use it in that much bulk  Or ask them for API ?**

You can use this way.

1. Encode your url.
    use **[urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)**
2. Add your encode url to 
   `$url='http://tinyurl.com/create.php?source=indexpage&url=<encoded url>`
3. Create a dom object
   `$doc=new DomDocuement();`
4. Load the page.
   `$doc->loadHTMLFile($url); // this is page containing shorten url`
5. Grab the node that contains `shorten url` ..*Second `blockquote` contains shorten url* 
   `$nodelist=$doc->getElementsByTagName('blockquote');`
   `$blockquote=$nodelist->item(1) // grabbing shorten url blockquote 0:first 1:second`
6. Now Grab shorten url : 
    `$shorten_url=$blockquote->$firstChild->NodeValue`
7. Use any where you like.

   For more info see [tiny url page structure](http://tinyurl.com/create.php?source=indexpage&url=www.facebook.com)
   Read more about [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
   For goo.gl, read: https://developers.google.com/url-shortener